# Images refreshed without reload the page

Tags: php, jquery, imagesource

I have a page that loads 200 or more images on one page. 
All images load fine but after a few seconds, I am sending a request using

```
setInterval(function() {
   var d = new Date();
   $("#img<?php echo $row['id']; ?>").attr("src", "<?php echo SS_TLRM_IMG_EDITOR.str_replace("../","",$row['src_path']).$row['image_name']; ?>?"+d.getTime()); },
8000);
```

and I load new images to this same page. I call this function in a `while` loop.

**What I am looking for:**

Is there a way to refresh just the images that have been changed?

***What is meant by change?***

Actually, I have two pages one is used for editing images and the other is a viewer I am using `wPaint js` for editing images. Below you'll find screenshots of both pages.

**VIEW PAGE**
[image]

**Editor Page**

[image]

**Editor page code**

```
//while loop start here

<div class="wPaint" id="edit_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" style="position:relative; width:<?php echo $width.'px'; ?>; height:<?php echo $height.'px'; ?>; margin:60px auto 20px auto;">
  <input type="hidden" class="editEnable" value="0">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="saveImgBtn" id="saveImg<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Save Image</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function saveImg(image) {
    var _this = this;
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      <?php if($_REQUEST['nz']==1){ ?>
      url: 'ajax/upload-nz.php?imgName=<?php echo $row['
      image_name ']; ?>&imgID=<?php echo $row['
      id ']; ?>',
      <?php }else{?>
      url: 'ajax/upload.php?imgName=<?php echo $row['image_name ']; ?>&imgID=<?php echo $row['id ']; ?>',
      <?php } ?>
      data: {
        image: image
      },
      success: function(resp) {
        if (resp == 1 || parseInt(resp) == 1) {
          _this._displayStatus('Image saved successfully');
          $(this).find(".editEnable").attr('value', '2');
          setTimeout(function() {
            $("#saveImg<?php echo $row['id']; ?>").css({
              'pointer-events': '',
              'opacity': '1'
            });
          }, 800);
        } else {
          alert('Some one delete this image. You can not edit or save this image now.');
        }
      }
    });
  }

  // both funciton use to load image on page load
  function loadImgBg() {
    this._showFileModal('bg', images);
  }

  function loadImgFg() {
    this._showFileModal('fg', images);
  }

  // init wPaint
  $('.wPaint').wPaint({
    path: '', // set absolute path for images and cursors
    autoScaleImage: true, // auto scale images to size of canvas (fg and bg)
    autoCenterImage: true, // auto center images (fg and bg, default is left/top corner)
    menuHandle: false, // setting to false will means menus cannot be dragged around
    menuOffsetLeft: 0,
    menuOffsetTop: -90,
    saveImg: saveImg,
    loadImgBg: loadImgBg,
    loadImgFg: loadImgFg,
    bg: '<?php echo SS_TLRM_IMG_EDITOR.str_replace("../","",$row['
    src_path ']).$row['
    image_name ']; ?>?cache=<?php echo str_replace(" ","",microtime()); ?>', // set bg on init  
    imageStretch: false, // stretch smaller images to full canvans dimensions

    mode: 'text',
    fontSize: '40',
    fillStyle: '#FF0000',
    fontBold: true,
    strokeStyle: '#F00',
  });
</script>

//while loop ended here
```

**View Page Code**

```
//while loop start here

<div id="edit_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" style="position:relative; width:<?php echo $width.'px'; ?>; height:<?php echo $height.'px'; ?>; margin:0px auto 20px auto;">
  <span id='ex<?php echo $row[' id ']; ?>' class="zoom"><img src='<?php echo SS_TLRM_IMG_EDITOR.str_replace("../","",$row['src_path']).$row['image_name']; ?>?cache=<?php echo str_replace(" ","",microtime()); ?>' id="img<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />
  </span>
</div>
<script>
  setInterval(function() {
    // Date use to prevent browser cache
    var d = new Date();
    $("#img<?php echo $row['id']; ?>").attr("src", "<?php echo SS_TLRM_IMG_EDITOR.str_replace(".. / ","
      ",$row['src_path']).$row['image_name']; ?>?" + d.getTime());
  }, 15000);
</script>

//while loop ended here
```

Comment: Let me get this straight: you are running a JavaSript (ie. Jquery) refresh and using PHP in that? JS runs on client side, PHP on server side so it's not going to work. You have to either run the refresh completely with JS/Jquery or load "remote" content (another page) generated by PHP.

Comment: i think you make a interval which listen for what image was changed, then reload it. That mean you implement and api for server to return list of changed images

Comment: More code is required to understand how you are trying to do what you want to do and detect where the errors might be.

Comment: @DocWeird When someone edits the image the user must click on a save button, Then I replace the previous image with the new one.

Comment: @MarcCompte Let me more clear to you. I have folder **upload** there I save 200 images. These images load on a **Editor Page** and **View Page**. If someone edits only one image and clicks on a save button then I want to refresh only that image on a view page. Currently, I am sending 200 calls to Refresh all images.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. You can only do "cross tab" scripting if you create the "view" tab from "Editor" tab. This way you could call a function insider the viewer (refreshImage(imagenumber), for example). To get around this you could perhaps create a file on the server (with a PHP-script you call from the page) telling you which file has changed, and a time stamp, and then poll that file from the viewer tab with Jquery. After you have read and done the changes in the viewer tab, empty the file again (with another call to the PHP-script). Just a thought.

Comment: @DocWeird When I tag you in a comment you get an alert in StackOverflow inbox right? I want this functionality on my web page. :)

Comment: @DocWeird Create a sperate file and send ajax call, again and again, is it the right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your php code loads once when the page is loaded. Your setInterval doesn't re-initialize your php code.

You can do one of three things.

1.Create an ajax call that requests the images table and updates when necessary and put the ajax call in the setInterval

2.When submitting a change have a proper php response with the image id stored in a new variable, let's say newId and the new imgSrc in a variable newImgSrc. Then with:

```
$("#img"+newId).attr("src", newImgSrc+"?"+d.getTime());
```

you can update directly the affected image.

3. When you load the page you can store all images using jquery. To do that you would need either a common selector or a parent for the images. SO you could enclose all images in a div with id="images-parent". In this case you can put everything in a setInterval and update like this:

   `setInterval(function() {
      var d = new Date();
      $("#images-parent").children("img").each(function() {
       var newImgSrc = $(this).attr("src");
       $(this).attr("src",newImgSrc+"?"+d.getTime());
      });
   },8000);`

Comment: Sending ajax requests, again and again, is that right approach? You confusing the question I have two different web pages. One is used for edit images and second is used for a view. I don't think the 2nd approach is valid.

Comment: Then try the first one. Also as I clearly state, that would be my preferred approach.

Comment: I comment you and you get alerted on your web page. I want this functionality on my VIEW page. And I am sure StackOverflow not sending ajax calls again and again.

Comment: Let me edit my response with yet another approach, give me 2 minutes

Comment: I am currently doing the same thing. You just use each loop of javascript and I am using PHP loop and inside this loop, I am using my JS code.